# How to do lazy loading with BXSlider

Tags: jquery, html, css, bxslider, lazy-loading

I am using an image gallery using [Bxslider](http://bxslider.com/). I am having more than 15 images in the slide which is taking a lot of time to load. So i need to load images in each slider one by one when that particular slide appears. I got an Example from here [lazyload and bxslider](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/issues/118) which uses LazyLoad to load the images. But its not working for me. Can any one help me with this?

Im using this code

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#moreLessons").bxSlider( { 
        startingSlide:1,
        pager: false
    });
    // trigger lazy to load new in-slided images
    $("a.bx-prev, a.bx-next").bind("click", function() {
        // extra call for lazy loading
        setTimeout(function() { $(window).trigger("scroll"); }, 100);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please show the code you're using so we can be to further assistance

Comment: Sorry, but *"it's not working"* is not a description of a problem. In it's current form, your question cannot reasonably be answered... voting to close.

Comment: look in the console to see if you get any errors

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="slider">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/200">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class="lazy" src="http://placekitten.com/450/200" data-src="http://placekitten.com/450/200">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class="lazy" src="http://placekitten.com/500/200" data-src="http://placekitten.com/500/200">
   </div>
</div>

$(function(){

    // create an options object to store your slider settings
    var slider_config = {
        mode: 'horizontal', // place all slider options here
        onSlideBefore: function($slideElement){
            var $lazy = $slideElement.find(".lazy")
            var $load = $lazy.attr("data-src");
            $lazy.attr("src",$load).removeClass("lazy");
             alert(JSON.stringify($lazy));
        }
    }
    // init the slider with your options
    var slider = $('.slider').bxSlider(slider_config);
});
```

Comment: Is that correct that "lazy" images have attr src set to the correct image? Shouldn't it be empty or copy of the first image? Good job by the way!

Answer (score 0):

You can 'trick' the browser to move 1 px by adding:
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()+1); to fire on a.bx-prev and a.bx-next 
You can then set:
$(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop()-1); to fire immediately after the events are called.
So if the slideshow is 50 images you will not have scrolled down the page 50px by the end.

This method will also work with bxslider in Drupal 7 with the addition of lazyload module. Simply enable lazyload, set the loading icon to 'none' and add the above javascript calls to the callback section of bxslider settings in your view. Voila! Go ahead and put all the hi-rez images in there you like.